# How to work with list in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
name           salary  skills
Web-master     2000     ['django', 'html', 'java']
Engineer       2700     ['python', 'java', 'sql']
Programer      2400     ['python', 'css', 'sql']
```

I want to create a dataframe like the below:

```
name    count  meansalary
django   1       2000
python   2       2550
java     2       2350
```

I tried this:

```
skildf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['skill','count', 'salary']) 

for i in data['skills']: 
  for j in i: 
    if j in skildf['skill']: 
      skildf.loc[j] = skildf.loc[j][['salary'] = i['salary'], ['count'] = 0]
    else: 
      skildf.loc[j] = skildf.loc[j][['salary'] += i['salary'], ['salary'] += 1]
```

Comment: Please share the code which you tried?

Comment: i tried this:''' skildf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['skill','count', 'salary'])
for i in data['skills']:
  for j in i:
    if j in skildf['skill']:
      skildf.loc[j] = skildf.loc[j][['salary'] = i['salary'], ['count']  = 0]
    else:
      skildf.loc[j] = skildf.loc[j][['salary'] += i['salary'], ['salary'] += 1]'''

Answer (score 3):

```
out = (df.explode("skills")
         .groupby("skills")
         .agg(count=("skills", "size"), meansalary=("salary", "mean")))
```

`explode` the lists and then groupby over the individual `skills`. Then `agg`regrate over `skills`' size to get the `count` column and over `salary`'s `mean` to get `meansalary`

to get

```
>>> out

        count  meansalary
skills
css         1        2400
django      1        2000
html        1        2000
java        2        2350
python      2        2550
sql         2        2550
```